# how to add @ to postgres hibernate dialect?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, full-text-search, hql

We have a native query for full text search that uses a GIN index like so:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_column1 ON table1 USING gin (to_tsvector('english', column1));

SELECT *
FROM table1
where to_tsvector('english', column1) @@ to_tsquery('searchedText')
```

However, we were unable to replicate this query in HQL, because hibernate errors on symbol @. 
How to add symbol @ to the hibernate dialect?

Comment: The Hibernate folks seem to think it's weird to want to do this ("not portable", "just use Hibernate Search", etc) so information is hard to come by.

Comment: I hope that this article will help you - http://java-talks.blogspot.com/2014/04/use-postgresql-full-text-search-with-hql.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find it in [this link](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2447426), that link will guide you to :

- recognize that SQLFunctions have to return a value and when used in
  HQL must be in an expression form (e.g., fts(body, 'dog') = true --
  fts(body, 'dog') won't work in HQL)
- create a Hibernate SQLFunction for PG FTS; and
- remember that the expression "to_tsvector(body) @@ to_tsquery('dog')"
  evaluates to a boolean

Comment: Thanks. This clue "(e.g., fts(body, 'dog') = true -- fts(body, 'dog') won't work in HQL)" did really help me.